# How to show elements of user from web to a listview of android

Tags: android, json, web-services, android-volley

here i want to show the elements of particular user into a listview of android, but at response i got the error as "end of input at character 0 of json" along with nullpointerexception, so can anyone suggest me the solution!

//MainActivity.Java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/api.php";

    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "id";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "api_key";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "type";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
    private EditText editTextUsername;
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    String result="";

    private ListView lv;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private Button buttonLogin;
    private TextView txtview;
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        contactList = new ArrayList<>();
       // txtview=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        buttonLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin);


        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void UserShow(){
        final String username = "117";
        final String password = "pass";
        final String email="get_earn";

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        InputStream ss=null;
                        //convert response to string
                        try{
                            //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                            String line = null;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sb.append(line + "\n");
                            }
                            ss.close();
                            result=sb.toString();
                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                        }
                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

                            // Getting JSON Array node
                            JSONArray contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

                            // looping through All Contacts
                            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                                String id = c.getString("name");
                                String name = c.getString("disc");

                                // tmp hash map for single contact
                                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                                contact.put("name", id);
                                contact.put("disc", name);

                                // adding contact to contact list
                                contactList.add(contact);


                             }
                        } catch (final JSONException e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            });

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[]{ "name","disc"},
                                new int[]{R.id.email, R.id.mobile});
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                    }

                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("id","username");
                params.put("api_key","pasword");
                params.put("type", "email");
                return params;
            }

        };

        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonRegister){
            registerUser();
        }
        if(v == buttonLogin){
            UserShow();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @CoDFather I want to use post method for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to process InutStream thing here... you are already getting the response in as a string in onResponse() as param. Just convert it to JSON object and process.. in short just remove

```
InputStream ss=null;
                    //convert response to string
                    try{
                        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ss,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        ss.close();
                        result=sb.toString();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                    }
```

section and convert `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);` 
to  `JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);` and process the jsonObj to get intented information.

Comment: it shows all json...i only required parametres of "result" objects

Comment: you need to fetch result JSONAraay from jsonObj as you are already doing, after getting jsonObj.